# C++: class "X" has no member named "Y"

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, include

I have two projects: **Project A** & **Project B**.
In Project A, I have the class: 1.

I've included the class '1' from Project A using "#include '1' & using the configuration in eclipse.

When I try to access a public method from class 1 in Project B I'm getting the error:
Class "A" has no member named "Test".

What am I doing wrong???

EDIT: The class name & method is for skeleton purposes.

Project "MGeneral" has a class called "MGeneralCommands" -

```
class MGeneralCommands
{
    public:

        void sendCommand(TCPSocket * sock,int command);
        void sendData(TCPSocket * sock,string data);
        int readCommand(TCPSocket * sock);
        string readData(TCPSocket * sock);
};
```

Project "MSA" has a class called "TCPMessengerServer" in which I’ve used "`#include "MGeneralCommands.h"`". For example, when trying to call the method "sendCommand" it won't recognize it.

Comment: Please, provide the code.

Comment: Please consider showing at least an outline of your code - just the skeleton

Comment: The name of your class should be "1"?

Comment: Could you give a minimal code example?  Also, are you attempting to link to "project A" as a library?  Just a simple guess, but be sure you've included the header and source files in your project.

Comment: Post was edited with further information.

Comment: Could you post all the error messages you're getting, as well as how you are trying to call "sendCommand"?

Comment: Could you show us the code that tries to call the method? That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: I've checked it once again, and it recognizes other includes from that class but not the public methods.

Comment: The call: sendData(socket,"TEST");
The error: ‘sendData’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Also, is this a compiler error, or just Eclipse failing to find a declaration in one project when analysing another? It won't find it unless you've set up the project references (Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References).

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's a compiler error. Eclipse can't compile my code.

Comment: @Erez: You need to call the method on an object of type `MGeneralCommands`: `commands.sendData(socket,"Test");` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the error is actually something completely different:

```
‘sendData’ was not declared in this scope
```

from the code

```
sendData(socket,"TEST");
```

Unless you're already in a member function of `MGeneralCommands` (or a subclass), you'll need an object of that type to call it on:

```
commands.sendData(socket,"TEST");
```